# Second derivative of norm of matrix power $\lVert y - A^kx \rVert$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I am looking for the second derivative w.r.t $A$ (and $x$ and $y$, but those are a little easier):

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial A^2} \frac{1}{2} \lVert y - A^kx \rVert_2^2
$$

I can find the first derivative with [www.matrixcalculus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial A} \frac{1}{2} \lVert y - A^kx \rVert_2^2 = -k \cdot diag(y - A^kx)A^{k-1}\cdot diag(x)
$$

But handling the "diag" operator wasn't clear. I am attempting/hoping to show that the Lipschitz constant used for gradient descent depends on $k$.

Comment: what does $k$ represent?

Comment: @user550103 - it's a scalar integer. In my particular use case, it represents "time" over which the discrete linear system described by $A$ is rolled forward. I should have put that in the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is the differential
$$\eqalign{
dA^k &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} A^{j}\,dA\,A^{k-j-1}\cr
}$$
Define $w = (A^kx-y)$ and $B=A^T\,\,$ then find the gradient (first derivative) 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|w\|^2_2 = w:w \cr 
d\phi &= 2w:dw = 2w:dA^kx = 2wx^T:dA^k \cr
 &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2wx^T:A^{j}\,dA\,A^{k-j-1} \cr
 &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2B^{j}wx^TB^{k-j-1}:dA \cr
G=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A} &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2B^{j}wx^TB^{k-j-1} \cr
}$$ where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $M:P={\rm Tr}(M^TP)$

Note that the gradient is a matrix. That means that the Hessian (second derivative) will be a fourth-order tensor -- which is the reason why the website won't try to calculate it.

In order to calculate the Hessian, the $w$ and $B^i=(A^T)^i$ terms must be differentiated leading to a complicated double summation. Start by finding the differential of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dG
 &= 2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} &dB^{j}wx^TB^{k-j-1}+B^{j}dA^kxx^TB^{k-j-1}+B^{j}wx^TdB^{k-j-1} \cr
 &= 2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Bigg(&\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}B^{i}\,dB\,B^{j-i-1}wx^TB^{k-j-1}
  + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}B^{j}A^{i}\,dA\,A^{k-i-1}xx^TB^{k-j-1} \cr
  &\,&+ \sum_{i=0}^{k-j-2}B^{j}wx^TB^{i}\,dB\,B^{j-i-1}
  \Bigg) \cr
}$$
At this point you can use vectorization to flatten the matrices into vectors and calculate the Hessian as the matrix, i.e. 
$$g={\rm vec}(G),\,\,\,a={\rm vec}(A) \implies H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$$
Or you can find the Hessian in tensor form using index notation.

Or perhaps the differential expression is sufficient for whatever purpose you have in mind.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I will go through this and try to understand it more deeply. I bet I can formulate the inequality for the Lipschitz constant in terms of the differential expression: $\lVert \nabla \phi(w_0) - \nabla \phi(w_1) \rVert_2 \leq L \lVert w_0 - w_1 \rVert_2$